# My window closed immediatly when I launch my code

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgis

I'm trying to display a window in which I want to enter some parameters but the window is empty and close just after the end of the function.

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code please ?
(I tried to work with QApplication but my software (QGIS) crashed)

Here is my code :

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #...
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(320, 140))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Test") 
        #...
        self.label_1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_1.setText('Numéro du département étudié :')
        self.line_1 = QLineEdit(self)
        #...
        self.line_1.move(100, 20)
        self.line_1.resize(200, 32)
        self.label_1.move(40, 20)
        #...
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_2.setText('Nombre de points de départ :')
        self.line_2 = QLineEdit(self)
        #...
        self.line_2.move(100, 60)
        self.line_2.resize(200, 32)
        self.label_2.move(40, 60)
        #...
        self.label_3 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_3.setText("Chemin d'accès jusqu'a la liste des départements : (doit finir par un '/')")
        self.line_3 = QLineEdit(self)
        #...
        self.line_3.move(100, 100)
        self.line_3.resize(200, 32)
        self.label_3.move(40, 100)
        #...
        pybutton = QPushButton('Valider ma saisie', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        pybutton.resize(200,32)
        pybutton.move(80, 140)        
        #...
    def clickMethod(self):
        params = []
        params.append(self.line_1.text())
        params.append(self.line_2.text())
        params.append(self.line_3.text())
        #...
    def start(self):
        mainWin = MainWindow()
        mainWin.show()
```

Comment: just have to save the code in a file and to import this file in your python editor :)

Comment: I mean, this code doesn't do anything besides importing some modules and building the class. It doesn't instantiate the class or call any functions/methods to open a window or anything.

Comment: I have not asked how to execute your code, even if you follow what you say nothing is shown, your code is just a class without instantiating any object as indicated by ForceBru.

Comment: After importing this I launch this code with 'MainWindow.start(PyQt5.QWidgets)

Answer (score 0):

A `QApplication` must be created before creating a `QWidget`.

Import:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

Create application:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Your entire code will be:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #...
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(320, 140))
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Line Edit example (textfield) - pythonprogramminglanguage.com")
        #...
        self.label_1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_1.setText('Numéro du département étudié :')
        self.line_1 = QLineEdit(self)
        #...
        self.line_1.move(100, 20)
        self.line_1.resize(200, 32)
        self.label_1.move(40, 20)
        #...
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_2.setText('Nombre de points de départ :')
        self.line_2 = QLineEdit(self)
        #...
        self.line_2.move(100, 60)
        self.line_2.resize(200, 32)
        self.label_2.move(40, 60)
        #...
        self.label_3 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_3.setText("Chemin d'accès jusqu'a la liste des départements : (doit finir par un '/')")
        self.line_3 = QLineEdit(self)
        #...
        self.line_3.move(100, 100)
        self.line_3.resize(200, 32)
        self.label_3.move(40, 100)
        #...
        pybutton = QPushButton('Valider ma saisie', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        #pybutton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        pybutton.resize(200,32)
        pybutton.move(80, 140)
        #...
    def clickMethod(self):
        params = []
        params.append(self.line_1.text())
        params.append(self.line_2.text())
        params.append(self.line_3.text())
        params.append(self.line_4.text())
        params.append(self.line_5.text())
        params.append(self.line_6.text())
        #...


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I never understood what is this '__name__' and what is his value.. ?

Comment: My pleasure. If it solved your problem, please accept and upvote. This video may give you a better understanding of `__name__` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJHeSRKWtfM